# Why is this media query applying to all viewport widths?

Tags: html, css

I'm a new programmer - finishing my last project for my first web dev class.  I have a web page that looks the way I want it to look, over 1409px in width.  I'm trying to make it responsive, so that it will change once the width drops to 1409px or below.  I have this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And my media query is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1408px)
{
.background {
    height:100%;
  }

}
```

But once I add this query and save it in my style sheet, it applies my change (making the background height 100%) all the time to all widths!  Why would this be?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the only code you have? can you share both HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Can you post some more code? this is difficult to determine with just this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .background class without media query and provide height's value which you need for other resolution or add **height : 'auto'** because the browser will apply this media query style if there is no other style present by default for other resolutions.

Comment: _“because the browser will apply this media query style if there is no other style present by default for other resolutions”_ - that is, of course, absolutely not true.

Comment: This turned out to be working just fine. It just wasn't displaying correctly in Chrome on my laptop.  I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to post your HTML code as well. What I understand from your question, is you are having trouble with a `div` with a class `background` and you may have the following solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
 Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background{
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media(min-width: 1409px){
  .background{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/OJyZKzG

Comment: This turned out to be working just fine. It just wasn't displaying correctly in Chrome on my laptop.  I'm really sorry.